# Doing the Prostration of Forgetfulness twice

Tags: salat

When I was praying Isha I was unsure if I didn't completely say subhanarabialala 3 times during sajda, so at the end I did the prostration of forgetfulness before the Salam, but I was not sure if I did it correctly. I assumed because it was a doubt I should ignore it and just say Salam. But then after I started to worry so I did Prostration of Forgetfulness again, this time it was after the Salam. And I said Salam again after that. Do you know if my prayer will be accepted or do I have to repeat it?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it is better that you repeat the prayer if you are unsure that you did it correctly and you forgot saying "Subhanarabiallah" 3 times during Sajda.  When praying Salat(Namaz) prayer, your mind needs to be focused on you and your lord, Allah subhanu wa ta ala, without any distractions in your way.  If you do have too many distractions in your way for the whole day, then making sincere repentance to Allah will do, until you find a quiet area and the time to do the prayers.  In these times, I know from experience that making Prayers or making up Prayers can be difficult to perform due to focusing on the dunya (e.g school, work) too much, but if you can make the time to please Allah by praying to him and not forgetting what to say during prayer, then do it as much as possible. Hope this answers your question.
Asalamaleikum